# maven jar dependency convergence on itself

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am getting below error

```
Dependency convergence error for com.test.myproject:common1:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT paths to dependency are:
+-com.test.myproject:common1:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
and
+-com.test.myproject:common1:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.test.myproject:common1:2.1.0.463
```

I have no reference to 2.1.0.463 anywhere. Not sure how it is coming and how to resolve it..Any pointers please?

Comment: Please add the POM of the project